# How to Replace Icon and title with a png logo

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

By default the native `ActionBar` show app name with app icon on the left. I want to replace all this section 
with a custom logo

[image]

searching seems that I have to edit the `styles.xml` file to customize the action bar, but I haven't understood what is the right way and what resolution should have the logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"By default, the system uses your application icon in the action bar, as specified by the icon attribute in the `<application>` or `<activity>` element. However, if you also specify the logo attribute, then the action bar uses the logo image instead of the icon."
source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

In order to remove the Title of the Activity you call `ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`